# Android Floating activity with dismiss on swipe

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

The latest Facebook's android app has a very nice floating comment window. There the user can dismiss the window swiping up or down making it really ease to use.

I want to implement a similar behaviour in my app but I don't know how to do it. Any idea or clue about how to do it will be really appreciated.

Screenshots of the Facebook app
(sorry, the Facebook app from where I took the screenshots is in Japanese)
[image: Swipe up]
[image: Swipe down]

Comment: I updated my answer with few screenshots ;)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I write some code that match this closing/resizing behaviour, **I don't know if it's the way to go but my code is based on Activity class**. First thing I do is create an activity and give it `Transluscent`theme to get an activity with transparent background.

**In my manifest.xml :**

```
<activity
    android:name=".PopupActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_popup"
    <!-- Use Translucent theme to get transparent activity background 
     and NoTitleBar to avoid super old style title bar ;) -->
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
</activity>
```

Then I create a simple layout file containing a textview (corresponding to Facebook tchatting part) and a view (corresponding to Facebook "Write your msg"/"send smiley" tab)

**my layout/activity_popup.xml :**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/base_popup_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_marginBottom="124dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally I handle touch and move event in my PopupActivity class, I use [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) which provide callback in onTouch method.

**PopupActivity**

```
public class PopupActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener{

    private RelativeLayout baseLayout;

    private int previousFingerPosition = 0;
    private int baseLayoutPosition = 0;
    private int defaultViewHeight;

    private boolean isClosing = false;
    private boolean isScrollingUp = false;
    private boolean isScrollingDown = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_popup);
        baseLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.base_popup_layout);
        baseLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        // Get finger position on screen
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();

        // Switch on motion event type
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // save default base layout height
                defaultViewHeight = baseLayout.getHeight();

                // Init finger and view position
                previousFingerPosition = Y;
                baseLayoutPosition = (int) baseLayout.getY();
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // If user was doing a scroll up
                if(isScrollingUp){
                    // Reset baselayout position
                    baseLayout.setY(0);
                    // We are not in scrolling up mode anymore
                    isScrollingUp = false;
                }

                // If user was doing a scroll down
                if(isScrollingDown){
                    // Reset baselayout position
                    baseLayout.setY(0);
                    // Reset base layout size
                    baseLayout.getLayoutParams().height = defaultViewHeight;
                    baseLayout.requestLayout();
                    // We are not in scrolling down mode anymore
                    isScrollingDown = false;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(!isClosing){
                    int currentYPosition = (int) baseLayout.getY();

                    // If we scroll up
                    if(previousFingerPosition >Y){
                        // First time android rise an event for "up" move
                        if(!isScrollingUp){
                            isScrollingUp = true;
                        }

                    // Has user scroll down before -> view is smaller than it's default size -> resize it instead of change it position
                    if(baseLayout.getHeight()<defaultViewHeight){
                        baseLayout.getLayoutParams().height = baseLayout.getHeight() - (Y - previousFingerPosition);
                        baseLayout.requestLayout();
                    }
                    else {
                        // Has user scroll enough to "auto close" popup ?
                        if ((baseLayoutPosition - currentYPosition) > defaultViewHeight / 4) {
                            closeUpAndDismissDialog(currentYPosition);
                            return true;
                        }

                        //
                    }
                    baseLayout.setY(baseLayout.getY() + (Y - previousFingerPosition));

                }
                // If we scroll down
                else{

                    // First time android rise an event for "down" move
                    if(!isScrollingDown){
                        isScrollingDown = true;
                    }

                    // Has user scroll enough to "auto close" popup ?
                    if (Math.abs(baseLayoutPosition - currentYPosition) > defaultViewHeight / 2)
                    {
                        closeDownAndDismissDialog(currentYPosition);
                        return true;
                    }

                    // Change base layout size and position (must change position because view anchor is top left corner)
                    baseLayout.setY(baseLayout.getY() + (Y - previousFingerPosition));
                    baseLayout.getLayoutParams().height = baseLayout.getHeight() - (Y - previousFingerPosition);
                    baseLayout.requestLayout();
                }

                // Update position
                previousFingerPosition = Y;
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

There are two small methods called when user has scroll enough to close popup (ie animate and finish activity) :

```
public void closeUpAndDismissDialog(int currentPosition){
    isClosing = true;
    ObjectAnimator positionAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(baseLayout, "y", currentPosition, -baseLayout.getHeight());
    positionAnimator.setDuration(300);
    positionAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener()
    {
        . . .
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator)
        {
            finish();
        }
        . . .
    });
    positionAnimator.start();
}

public void closeDownAndDismissDialog(int currentPosition){
    isClosing = true;
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int screenHeight = size.y;
    ObjectAnimator positionAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(baseLayout, "y", currentPosition, screenHeight+baseLayout.getHeight());
    positionAnimator.setDuration(300);
    positionAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener()
     {
        . . .
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator)
        {
            finish();
        }
        . . .
    });
    positionAnimator.start();
}
```

With all this code your should be able to start PopupActivity that globally match Facebook popup behaviour. It's just a draft class and a lot of work remains to do : add animations, work on closing parameters and so on...

**Screenshots :**

[image: Screenshot of PopupActivity as written above]

Comment: Nice answer but It is not working if view has scroll property

Comment: @Shah disable scroll when you want swap

Comment: @Gaëtan Maisse How to disable right-left swipe calls

Comment: How to disable swipe up and scroll the layout? thanks

Comment: any solution for scrolling layout eg: recyclerview?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use **BottomSheetDialogFragment** component from appcompat libarary. Check this article for the information:
https://medium.com/@nullthemall/new-bottomsheet-caab21aff19b#.gpu1l516z

You could also get useful information from 
[documentaion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment.html).

Answer (score 2):

Well, the OP title was asking for a floating activity, but the OP content was looking for a **floating comment window** that is like facebook comment window.

So, here this will be implemented by a `DialogFragment` which provide us with the behavior of automatically bouncing the dialog to its original state/window size whenever you swipe up or down. And this behavior is kept when the dialog is swiped a little (exactly swiped a distance less than the half of the original layout size).

The remaining thing is it dismiss this dialog if its size is less than the half of the original window size; in other words, if it's swiped greater than the half of the original layout size. This part is adjusted from the accepted answer by changing the only the `Y` position of the root layout of the dialog window, and without changing the size of the window as this provided weird resizing behavior.

First create this style to have a transparent background to the dialog window:

```
<style name="NoBackgroundDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

This style will be applied in the DialogFragment by overriding `getTheme()` method.

And here is the customized DialogFragment:

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment(), View.OnTouchListener {

    private var rootLayoutY: Int = 0
    private val rootLayout by lazy {
        requireView().findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.dialog_root)
    }

    private var oldY = 0
    private var baseLayoutPosition = 0
    private var defaultViewHeight = 0
    private var isScrollingUp = false
    private var isScrollingDown = false

    override fun getTheme(): Int {
        return R.style.NoBackgroundDialogTheme
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_dialog_facebook_comment, container,
            false
        )
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_background)

        return view
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Making the dialog full screen
        dialog?.window?.setLayout(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        rootLayout.setOnTouchListener(this)

        rootLayout.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
            OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                rootLayout.viewTreeObserver
                    .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                // save default base layout height
                defaultViewHeight = rootLayout.height
            }
        })

    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        // Get finger position on screen
        val y = event!!.rawY.toInt()


        // Switch on motion event type
        when (event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {

                // Init finger and view position
                oldY = y
                baseLayoutPosition = rootLayout.y.toInt()
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {

                if (rootLayoutY >= defaultViewHeight / 2) {
                    dismiss()
                    return true
                }

                // If user was doing a scroll up
                if (isScrollingUp) {
                    // Reset baselayout position
                    rootLayout.y = 0f
                    // We are not in scrolling up mode anymore
                    isScrollingUp = false
                }

                // If user was doing a scroll down
                if (isScrollingDown) {
                    // Reset baselayout position
                    rootLayout.y = 0f
                    //  Reset base layout size
                    rootLayout.layoutParams.height = defaultViewHeight
                    rootLayout.requestLayout()
                    // We are not in scrolling down mode anymore
                    isScrollingDown = false
                }

            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {

                rootLayoutY = abs(rootLayout.y.toInt())

                // Change base layout size and position (must change position because view anchor is top left corner)
                rootLayout.y = rootLayout.y + (y - oldY)

                if (oldY > y) { // scrolling up
                    if (!isScrollingUp) isScrollingUp = true
                } else { // Scrolling down
                    if (!isScrollingDown) isScrollingDown = true
                }

                // Update y position
                oldY = y
            }
        }
        return true
    }


}
```

In my case, the root layout of the dialog is a `ConstraintLayout`.

[image]