# how to dismiss Popup dialog when touch up or down like facebook comments popupup

Tags: android, dialog, touch, swipe, popupwindow

I try to dismiss popup dialog when user move up or down , any one can help me[image]

Comment: I have same problem , in my case I added a fragment in frame layout which contains list view. Did you find any solution?.

Comment: no i can't find any solution :(

Comment: Check This Link It is helpfull for u : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246981/android-floating-activity-with-dismiss-on-swipe

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your class,

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
```

And paste this code to detect up and down swipe,

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    try {
        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH){
            return false;
        }

        if (e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            onUpSwipe(); // your method or code of your requirement
        } 

        else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            onDownSwipe(); // your method or code of your requirement
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: but how move the popup dialog up or down and use this code with it