# how to use fragment or activity in windowManger service

Tags: android

i search for two dayes about how can i use fragment in service with WindowManger
i didn't find any thing about this i see many app use fragment as i think in windowmanger  lets see facebook messenger

[image]

i think this menu its fragment if its not fragment how can i do like it in windowManger with service

i just think about make activity inside service by make `inner class` but i think its stupid idea and i have many errors with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be  a floating activity in which you can put anything that you can do with the activity

For more reference refer this

[Android Floating activity with dismiss on swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246981/android-floating-activity-with-dismiss-on-swipe)

Comment: good answer but i still need more information how can i use it in `windowmanger` in `service` i vote up for your answer

Comment: from service you can start floating activity as you have context  from getapplicationContext() in service.